# AWK error when starting as a particular user

Tags: linux, awk, su

I am using YOCTO Linux and we have only one user 'root' for now.
I have a script that runs a process at power ON.

There was a requirement that log folder be created dynamically as per the user and found the solution (from stackoverflow) to run the module as below

```
/bin/su -c "/usr/local/bin/TestApplication &" - root
```

The above works without issues and Folders get created as expected too.

Now when I add 'AWK' command to add date and time to the process output i get error

**Command Used**

```
/bin/su -c "/usr/local/bin/TestApplication 2>&1| awk '{ print strftime("%F %T"), $0; fflush(); }' | tee /home/TestApplication.txt &" - root
```

**Error Message:**

```
awk: cmd. line:1: { print strftime(%F %T),/usr/local/bin/TestApplication_script;fflush();}
awk: cmd. line:1:                  ^ syntax error
```

**No Error if used like this:**

```
/usr/local/bin/TestApplication 2>&1| awk '{print strftime("%F %T"),$0;fflush();}' | tee /home/TestApplication.txt &
```

So the error only occurs if i try to use '/bin/su -c' please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `su` invocation removes one layer of shell quoting, and expands the `$0`.  awk is probably invoked with these arguments:

```
awk '{ print strftime(%F %T), /bin/sh; fflush(); }'
```

To prevent that, you need to quote the `"` and `$` characters in the original command line, like this:

```
…| awk '{ print strftime(\"%F %T\"), \$0; fflush(); }' |…
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the response. It made sense when I read you comment but for some weird reason i am getting a new error.

**This is the command after modification:**
/bin/su -c "/usr/local/bin/TestApplication 2>&1| awk '{ print strftime(\"%F_%T\"), $0; fflush(); }' | tee /home/TestApplication.txt &" - root


**New Error:**
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted

Comment: What's the new error? Oh, let me guess, I missed the `$0`.

Comment: I think the `\$0` should fix that as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. I almost spent a week trying to figure this out and tried every possible solution. It WORKS. Thank you so much.